# What is this pipe sticking out of the ground

Tags: pipe

I sold my dads house after he died & the people that bought it dug up the ground to fix the sewer line. I drove past the house the other day & saw this really tall white pipe sticking out of the ground by the windows. Does anyone know what this is? It’s been there for months now. [image]

Comment: What the mole people use to egress from the bowels of hell?

Comment: `Does anyone know what this is?` ... definitely yes, the person who installed it knows

Comment: Could be a cleanout on the house side of a 45/135 fitting that redirects to the line slanting across the yard.

Comment: Why ask us instead of stopping and asking the purchasers?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am not going to bother the new owners. I happen to drive past it the other day didn’t know what it was since the clean out thing is already in the yard. I googled it & came across this website. I am a female & know nothing about plumbing lol.

Answer (score 3):

Clean out access to the lateral sewer line from the house.

Comment: Probably waiting to relandscape the yard before trimming it down.